# Create a Insert... Select statement in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm needing to convert this query for Laravel and I'm having issues trying to create an Insert... Select statement using Laravel's Eloquont ORM, or Queries. I'm not sure how I would go about creating this query.

```
Insert into Demand (Login, Name, ApptTime, Phone, Physician, Location, FormatName, FormatDate, FormatTime, ApptDate, FormatPhone, cellphone)
Select Login, Name, ApptTime, Phone, Physician, Location, FormatName, FormatDate, FormatTime, ApptDate, FormatPhone, cellphone from " . [dbname] . "
    Where " . $where_statement
```

How is it possible to create this query using Laravel's ORM?

EDIT: I'm not sure if this is clear, but I'm thinking in terms of 1 query, like they do here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html

Comment: Please go through the documentation, that could be more helpful: http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent

Comment: I've been through the documentation, and have tried different chains. But I'm still not sure how to create this as ONE query versus 2.

Comment: Eloquent isn't really meant to take care of things like this.  You can just put the query inside `DB::statement()`.

Comment: Yeah, I ended up making it into 2 queries.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

There is no way of doing this in one query (unless you are on Laravel 5.7), however I came across the same issue and wanted to make sure I can keep using a certain select I build with the QueryBuilder.

So what you could do, to keep things half what clean and to reuse functionality which has built a select statement before, is this:

```
/**
 * Wherever your Select may come from
 **/
$select = User::where(...)
                  ->where(...)
                  ->whereIn(...)
                  ->select(array('email','moneyOwing'));
/**
 * get the binding parameters
 **/ 
$bindings = $select->getBindings();
/**
 * now go down to the "Network Layer"
 * and do a hard coded select
 */
 $insertQuery = 'INSERT into user_debt_collection (email,dinero) '
                . $select->toSql();
    
 \DB::insert($insertQuery, $bindings);
```

**UPDATE Laravel 5.7**

As of Laravel 5.7.17 you can use ->insertUsing(). See [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/commit/8216b4607152f9b01f26efba6b045add5382c625) for details. Thank you @Soulriser for pointing this out.

So above query would look like this:

```
DB::table('user_debt_collection')->insertUsing(['email','dinero'], $select);
```

Comment: this is really awesome.

Comment: With Laravel 5.7, you can simplify things with: `DB::table('user_debt_collection')->insertUsing(['email','dinero'], $select);`

Comment: Thank you @soulriser , I have updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: How would be the syntax if we wish to take some static string as column name ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean Sandeep ? You mean something like this? DB::table('user_debt_collection')->insertUsing([YourClass:COLUMN_NAME,YourClass::OTHER_COLUMN_NAME], $select); ??

Comment: Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::insertUsing  : https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_insertUsing

Answer (score 15):

You can use:

```
DB::insert("insert into contacts(contact_id,contact_type,account_id,created_at,updated_at) select f.id,'App\\Friend',f.account_id,f.created_at,f.updated_at from friends as f where f.id=?",[16]);
```

Answer (score 4):

I used DB::statement("...");

```
DB::statement("INSERT INTO table (SELECT)");
```

Answer (score 1):

In Laravel 5.5, I created a helper function for executing easier:

```
class QueryHelper
{

    /**
     * @param string $model
     * @param array $columns
     * @param Builder $select
     * @return bool
     */
    public static function insertFromSelectStatement($model, $columns, $select)
    {
        /** @var \Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder $query */
        $query = (new $model)->getQuery();
        $sql = "insert into {$query->from} (". implode(', ', $columns) .") {$select->toSql()}";
        return $query->getConnection()->insert($sql, $select->getBindings());
    }
}
```

For example:

```
$notification = Notification::create([
    'title' => 'this is title',
    'message' => 'this is message',
]);
$now = DB::raw("'". Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString() ."'");
$selectActivatedUsers = User::select('id', $notification->id, $now, $now)->where('status', '=', 'activated');
// insert notifications to activated users
QueryHelper::insertFromSelectStatement(UserNotification::class, ['user_id', 'notification_id', 'created_at', 'updated_at'], $selectActivatedUser);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
DB::table(table2)
    ->insert(
        (array) DB::table(table1)
            ->where('column', '=', $variable)
            ->select('column1','column2')
            ->first()
    );
```

Answer (score -1):

First, you'll need to create a model for `Demand`, so then you can use:

```
$demand = new Demand;
$demand->Login = $login;
$demand->Name = $name;
[...]
$demand->save(); // <~ this is your "insert" statement
$id = $demand->id;
```

Then for your select statement you can do something similar to these options:

```
$demand = Demand::find($id); // will be similar to: SELECT * FROM Demand WHERE `id` = '$id';
$demand = Demand::where('id', $id)->get(); //same as above
$demand = Demand::where('id', $id)->get(array('Login', 'Name')); // will be similar to: SELECT `Login`, `Name` FROM Demand WHERE `id` = '$id';
```

There is a lot more information in the manual [here](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#basic-usage) and [here](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#insert-update-delete)

Comment: The select statement is part of the insert. I've been through the documentations but I'm not seeing how to do something like this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html

Is there no way to do this using one query in Laravel? I know how I'd do it in 2, but it takes a minute to do this. I was wondering if there was something already built to create this one query.

Comment: I don't think you can do this within the Eloquent ORM...but I could be wrong

Comment: I haven't been able to find a way which is what brought up this question.