# How to implement oracle query to select from different tables in laravel

Tags: sql, laravel, oracle, eloquent

I'm trying to select distinct from different tables in laravel. In oracle I have implemented successfully the query and works. Now I'm trying to "translate" it into laravel. How can I do that?

In oraclesql the query is the following. TEMP table exists as well as all other tables used in this query. Is it possible to do this with DB::raw? Could you give me your advice please?

```
INSERT INTO TEMP (OBJECT_TYPE, OBLECT_ID)
SELECT DISTINCT HRP1001_CG.OBJECT_TYPE, HRP1001_CG.OBJECT_ID FROM HRP1001_SC, HRP1001_CG, CONFIG
WHERE
(HRP1001_SC.OBJECT_TYPE = 'CG')  
AND
(HRP1001_SC.REL_OBJ_TYPE = 'SC')   
AND
(HRP1001_SC.REL_OBJ_ID = CONFIG.SC)
AND
((HRP1001_SC.ST_DATE < CONFIG.DES_DATE) AND (HRP1001_SC.END_DATE > CONFIG.DES_DATE)) 
AND
(HRP1001_CG.REL_OBJ_ID = HRP1001_SC.OBJECT_ID)
AND
((HRP1001_CG.OBJECT_TYPE ='CG') OR (HRP1001_CG.OBJECT_TYPE ='SM'))
ORDER BY HRP1001_CG.OBJECT_ID;
```

update:
I also tried this code, but no result was received too :(.

```
$data = DB::table('hrp1001_sc')
            ->join('config', 'config.sc', '=', 'hrp1001_sc.rel_obj_id')
            ->join('config', 'config.des_date', '>', 'hrp1001_sc.st_date')
            ->join('config', 'config.des_date', '<', 'hrp1001_sc.end_date')
            ->join('hrp1001_cg', 'hrp1001_cg.rel_obj_id', '=', 
             'hrp1001_sc.object_id')
            ->where('hrp1001_sc.object_type', '=', 'cg')
            ->where('hrp1001_sc.rel_obj_type', '=', 'sc')
            ->select('hrp1001_sc.object_id')
            ->distinct()
            ->get();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create a Insert... Select statement in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25533608/create-a-insert-select-statement-in-laravel)

Comment: I tried with DB::Raw ("  my query ") but my temp table does not get populated. Can I do it without raw query? Any ideas are extremely welcome! Please assist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was found and this is it:

```
$q = "insert into temp(object_type, object_id)";
    $q = $q."select distinct hrp1001_cg.object_type, hrp1001_cg.object_id from 
    hrp1001_cg, hrp1001_sc, config where";
    $q =$q." hrp1001_sc.object_type = 'CG'";
    $q = $q." and hrp1001_sc.rel_obj_type = 'SC'";
    $q = $q." and hrp1001_sc.rel_obj_id = config.sc";
    $q = $q." and hrp1001_sc.st_date < config.des_date";
    $q = $q." and hrp1001_sc.end_date > config.des_date";
    $q = $q." and hrp1001_cg.rel_obj_id = hrp1001_sc.object_id";
    $q = $q." and";
    $q = $q." ((hrp1001_cg.object_type = 'CG') or (hrp1001_cg.object_type = 'SM'))";

    $xx = DB::insert($q);
```