# Removing square brackets from select query in laravel when using insertUsing (INSERT INTO.. SELECT)

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am relatively new to Laravel. I find myself having to do an INSERT based on a SELECT, like so:

```
INSERT INTO table2 (column1, column2, column3, ...)
SELECT column1, column2, column3, ...
FROM table1
WHERE condition;
```

I've learned that 'insertUsing' can be used for this in Laravel's eloquent. For the SELECT portion of the above, I have a few variables / static values that are set, like so. However, when I set these variables, Laravel will add square brackets to these values and my MS SQL database will give an error, as it recognize the value as a column name.

This is the code I use:

```
$select = Article::select($request->outboundid, $article, 'DESCRIPTION', 'NETTOWEIGHT', 'LENGTH', 'WIDTH', 'HEIGHT', $itemno, 1)
              ->where('ARTICLECODE', '=', $article);

    DB::table('TRITItemDimensions')
  ->insertUsing(['OUTBOUNDID','ARTICLE','GOODSDESCRIPTION','WEIGHT','LENGTH','WIDTH','HEIGHT','ITEMNO', 'FLAG'], $select);
```

But the actual insert will look like this:

```
insert into [TRITItemDimensions] ([OUTBOUNDID], [ARTICLE], [GOODSDESCRIPTION], [WEIGHT], [LENGTH], [WIDTH], [HEIGHT], [ITEMNO], [FLAG]) 
select [1049], [500069], [DESCRIPTION], [NETTOWEIGHT], [LENGTH], [WIDTH], [HEIGHT], [1], [1] from [TRITArticle] where [ARTICLECODE] = 500069
```

I've tried removing the brackets from the $articles PHP variable, but this gives errors. I can imagine that there's something to easily do this, but I can't for the life of me find it.

How do I remove the brackets from the 4 used variables ([1049], [500069], [1], [1]) in the query?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create a Insert... Select statement in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25533608/create-a-insert-select-statement-in-laravel)

Answer (score 1):

After some more investigating and trial and error, I found you can use DB::raw() to get the value without the square brackets. Not entirely sure if this is considered appropriate, but it worked.

```
$select = Article::select(DB::raw($request->outboundid), DB::raw($article), 'DESCRIPTION', 'NETTOWEIGHT', 'LENGTH', 'WIDTH', 'HEIGHT', DB::raw($itemno), DB::raw(1))
          ->where('ARTICLECODE', '=', $article);
```

Also, in this case you shouldn't use ->get(), as you pass a query builder instance as parameter of the InsertUsing (second query). If you add ->get(), an InvalidArgumentException is thrown:

```
"message": "A subquery must be a query builder instance, a Closure, or a string.",
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `->get()` at the end of your `$select` eloquent query. Otherwise, it remains as `eloquent query` object. When you call `->get()`, it will fetch the data.

Then, your insertUsing also need some brushup. You can follow this [link](https://laravel-news.com/laravel-5-7-17) to get a demo.