# Laravel DB::raw() failed but work in mysql directly

Tags: mysql, laravel

I am running a sql in Laravel:

```php
$last_reading_comprehension_id = DB::select(
    DB::raw("
        INSERT INTO `npee_reading_comprehensions`(npee_id) VALUES ($npee->id),($npee->id),($npee->id),($npee->id);
        SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
    ")
);
```

this will fail with errors
[image]

---

but when I run the sql directly in mysql, it works
[image]

Why it that? How can I solve it, thanks a lot for anyone help!

Comment: Looks like your `DB::select` does not support batch executionn (multi-query), so 2nd query in your batch fails.

Comment: @Akina Thanks a lot for your reply! `DB::raw()` sure can only run one sql inside

Answer (score 1):

I just found a similar case with answer. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25533608/create-a-insert-select-statement-in-laravel)

Not sure what's your laravel version, however, to perform 2 queries in laravel I would suggest to execute in separate DB queries as mentioned in the link and quote:

> There is no way of doing this in one query (unless you are on Laravel 5.7), however I came across the same issue and wanted to make sure I can keep using a certain select I build with the QueryBuilder.

```
 /**
  * Wherever your Select may come from
  **/
  $select = SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
  /**
   * get the binding parameters
   **/ 
  $bindings = $select->getBindings();
  /**
   * now go down to the "Network Layer"
   * and do a hard coded select, Laravel is a little
   * stupid here
   */
  $insertQuery = 'INSERT into npee_reading_comprehensions(npee_id) VALUES($npee->id),($npee->id),($npee->id),($npee->id)) '
            . $select->toSql();

  \DB::insert($insertQuery, $bindings);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a syntax error.

Corrected query : INSERT INTO `npee_reading_comprehensions`(npee_id) VALUES ('$npee->id'),('$npee->id'),('$npee->id'),('$npee->id');
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();

Comment: Thanks for your reply! But I've tried and I am sure it's not caused by `